# stop the jquery function after one execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the function `Nextthing` that hides first iframe and shows the next one, but as you will see in the code of the function I did just for only one next iframe, so if he makes the action for the second iframe to hides it and shows the next iframes it will display but in the wrong place.

How can I make the function to stop after one running?

```
function Nextthing (){

    $("#i").hide();
    $('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(2).after(
        '<tr><td colspan=10><iframe class="iframe"  src="/msg.html?msgId=' +
        $('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(2)
        .find('td a').eq(0).text()+'&constant=1"></iframe></td></tr>);
}
```

UPDATE: as you can see that iframe is called from that page msg.html, well that page has an input and a submit button, and the function `Nextthing` is called in that button like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="parent.Nextthing();" />
```

When somebody presses the submit button in the iframe it will load the iframe of the next page of msg.html based on msgId, and I want this load to be only once...

Comment: You can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

`.one()`  handler.. It will run the code once and stop the execution.

```
$('input[type=submit]').one('click', function() {
  $("#i").hide();
   $('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(2).after('<tr><td colspan=10><iframe class="iframe"     
    src="/msg.html?msgId='+$('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(2).find('td 
    a').eq(0).text()+'&constant=1"></iframe></td></tr>);

});
```

Comment: How are you calling the Nextitem() function

Comment: the i frame has a form with a submit button so when he submit the message it will hide the iframe and load the next iframe of the next message; it's like this `onclick="parent.Nextthing();`

Comment: Remove the onclick event from HTML and create the event using jQuery  $('input[type=submit]').one('click', function() {

Comment: so i want just to stop the execution of the second line in the function the one that adds the iframe again. i want the iframe to be added only one time.

Comment: won't work. you need parent.function() to work inside the iframe

Comment: Does parent mean the parent of submit button

Comment: really don't know, but i read a lot that you need parent to make that action work **inside** the iframe

Comment: how can i just execute `one` for the second line only ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this I usually just have a global variable such as elTriggers = false and check for that and make it true when it is triggered.  You could also check out jquery's [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.