# remove stops my action of submit in form inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [stop the jquery function after one execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678852/stop-the-jquery-function-after-one-execution)

I have this function:

```
function Nextthing (){

$("#i").hide();
$('.table').eq(1)
           .find('tbody tr')
           .eq(2)
           .after('<tr><td colspan=10><iframe class="iframe"  src="/msg.html?msgId='+$('.table')
           .eq(1)
           .find('tbody tr')
           .eq(2)
           .find('td a')
           .eq(0)
           .text()+'&constant=1"></iframe></td></tr>');
}

}
```

It's called on a submit button, but when I click the button, it hides that `#i` that is an iframe and it inserts a new I frame like the second statement of the function says.

*But* it doesn't pass the submit action, so it's like nothing happens but the effect and that's all.

Any alternative please of remove so it can pass the submit action?

Comment: Any errors reported by the browser?

Comment: no, no errors, just doesn't pass the submit at all

Comment: can't because i'm working with actions inside iframes so can't make a jsfiddle

Comment: submit action in the iframe that gets hidden?

Comment: the submit is inside the iframe yes, and when he clicks that submit, it will hide that iframe and loads the next one but the data of the submit are not passed, just the effect is working, the submit no.

Comment: You are missing a closing `'` in your code. Is that a typo?

Comment: did you get the answer you wanted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678852/stop-the-jquery-function-after-one-execution ?

Comment: no, i'm trying to resolve with `hide` if i can stop the execution of the second line. or better if `remove` work :(

Comment: could you a provide a temporary page in your server? also, you have an extra `}`

Comment: can't do that. i'm sorry, but `remove should work usually right ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is your submit handler. If that's the case you might have a problem since you are returning `undefined`. All JS functions return a value. If the value is not explicitly defined the value returned is `undefined` and since `undefined` is falsy your are returning false from and event handler which has the effect of canceling the event trigger i.e. canceling your submit

if that's the case simply insert a `return true;`at the end of the function

Comment: `return true;` didn't work :( , my idea works with `hide()` but i want to remove it all not just hide it :(

Answer (score 0):

Forms within hidden `iframe`s (that is, those with a style of `display: none`) will not submit. I believe this is a security measure to prevent phishing. You can, however, set `visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;` and it should work.

**EDIT:**

So the issue is actually not with the `$('#i').hide();`, but actually when it is changed to `$('#i').remove();`. In that case, you'll most likely want to change the code which runs in the `iframe` itself. Assuming some kind of server-side language capable of emitting HTML, after processing the form submission, output something like this:

```
<script>
if (parent && parent.Nextthing) {
    parent.Nextthing();
}
</script>
```

That assumes that the `Nextthing` function you show in your question is globally scoped, and included in the page which has the `iframe` reference.

Comment: it's working with `hide`, it's not working with `remove`... and i want with remove...

Comment: Okay, so the sample code says `hide` but that's not the problem. It's hard to help when the question and the code don't align. I would guess it would be a similar problem however; when you call `remove` the `iframe` is removed from the DOM. Why would a browser submit a form which no longer exists?

Comment: right, so what an alternativ could i use to submit and then execute my function? something to remove `#i` and add the iframe in the second line of the function

Comment: If you have control over the code which is running in the `iframe` you could call your function from the page which comes up after submission. So, in your `iframe`, have code which calls `parent.Nextthing();`, assuming `Nextthing()` is a globally-scoped function.

Comment: yes, i have control, and how can i do that?

Comment: i tried to do with `onsubmit` but the effect is not working with this ..

Comment: See my edit. Basically, you want code which runs when the form submission is complete. How you do that depends on your server-side language.

Comment: I'm afraid I've hit my limit of explanation time. Basically, there's no way to do what you're asking with `remove()`. If this explanation and possible workaround does not meet your needs, I apologize.